# How to indent the first line of footnotes

Tags: formatting, footnotes

I would like the first line of footnotes to be indented, like below. It seems the easier approach is to override the template using YAML at the top of my input document, but I don't know what to insert in the YAML.

[image]

Comment: use 'footmisc' package

Comment: What is "YAML"? [Yet Another Markup Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML)? If so, why place your query on TeX.SE?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're working with a LaTeX document, I'm interpreting your query as wishing to *increase* the indentation of the first line of each footnote relative to the default. (The default indentation amount is generally set by the LaTeX document class that's in use. In many (most?) document classes I'm familiar with, the default indentation amount ranges from `1.5em` to `1.8em`.)

In order to, say, *double* the indentation amount relative to the default, I suggest your execute the following instructions in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{footmisc}
\setlength\footnotemargin{2\footnotemargin}
```

Aside: If your document loads both the `ragged2e` and the `footmisc` packages, the `ragged2e` package should be loaded first.

Comment: I put this in different places, before the document class, and after the document class, and near footnote code. It didn't work, but I don't know what I am doing. ragged2e is not in the template.

I could send you the template I am using, but I understand if you don't want to do that.

Comment: @william - What exactly does "it didn't work" entail? Please clarify if you even use LaTeX. Or is it YAML? (It still isn't clear to me that you actually use LaTeX...) Incidentally, I wrote "execute the following instructions *in the preamble*" [emphasis added]. This definitely excludes executing the instructions either before `\documentclass` or after `\begin{document}`.  Please feel free to edit your initial posting to explain more clearly (a) what you're doing (some code that shows how you're creating footnotes would likely be helpful) and (b) what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I am using LaTex. The Pandoc Manual discusses the use of YAML variables to control output when using LaTex to convert to PDF. But, here I am concerned with the LaTex template.

I redid, entering your two lines in the preamble, between `\documentclass[` & `\begin{document}`. I picked a place that seemed appropriate.

I saved the change in the LaTex document. I converted a markdown document to PDF using this template. The footnotes were unchanged; the first line still hanged instead of being indented.

Comment: @william - Feel free to divulge which document class you employ.

Comment: I got your lines to produce the intended result. I inserted your lines right after `\usepackage{setspace}`. Then, I got an error there were too many curly quotes, and I removed the last curly quote from `\setlength\footnotemargin{2\footnotemargin}}`. That made it all work. Thanks for sticking with me.

Comment: @william - Thanks for pointing out the coding error. I've fixed it now.